# QGIS: apply coordinate georeferences to polygon layer

Tags: qgis

First time using qgis. I imported a .tif file (old map), then defined some boundaries by creating a layer of polygons.

Then, I attempted to georeference the map using these instructions [here](https://guides.lib.utexas.edu/georeference-raster-data/qgis-georeference-by-map-features).

However, I cannot seem to get the coordinate references to apply to the boundary polygons.

Grateful for any suggestions for where I am going wrong.